# Center header logo in Bartik theme

Tags: theming

I am using the Bartik theme in Drupal 7.15 and would like to have the header logo centered rather than left-aligned, is there some little piece of CSS I can add in with `drupal_add_css()` that will center the logo image? I need it to center correctly based on the width of the header image, so fake centering just using left padding isn't an option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A rule like this should do it:

```
#logo {
  display: block;
  width: 100px; // width of the image
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: That rule doesn't seem to center the logo, and also I don't know the width of the image because the logo will be changed by the admin relatively frequently.

Comment: Ah that's not much help then. I would try just making the container and the image itself (and maybe the wrapping `<a>` tab) `text-align:center;`, that ought to do it

Comment: Putting in `text-align:center;` everywhere doesn't seem to do anything to the alignment of the logo image. I'm using Chrome 22.

Comment: You've probably got some other styles acting on the image already then, perhaps it's floated?

Comment: Wasn't floated, but I have got it working, thanks for your input with this.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this CSS with `drupal_add_css()` makes the logo center:

```
#logo     { padding-left: 50%; }
#logo img { margin-left: -50%; }
```